# How to connect data IBOutlet to UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Im new in iOS programming. I have 1 question , I have searched in google and this page but I couldn't find answer.

- I want to build a simple Contact Demo. It has 2 view
- First view , I have a UITableView with null data, and 1 Add button. When I click add button, it will appear second view
- Second view, it has form and 1 Save button. After I fill out the form, I click Save Button, and I want it update to cell of UITableView, but it does not work.

Sorry my bad English, hope you can understand

Here is my code : 
First, file Contact.h to store Data

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Contact : NSObject{

}

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *phoneNumber;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *company;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *email;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *address;

@end
```

Handle Event when click Save Button ( in Second View):

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender
{

    Contact *c = [[Contact alloc] init];
    c.name = self.nameText.text;
    c.company = self.comText.text;
    c.phoneNumber = self.phoneText.text;
    c.email = self.emailText.text;
    c.address = self.addressText.text;

    /*telephoneViewController is a class that store my TableView ( it is the first view)
    */
    TelephoneViewController *tv = [[TelephoneViewController alloc] init];
    tv.dataObj = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [tv.tableView beginUpdates];
    [tv.dataObj addObject:c];

    [tv.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tv.dataObj withRowAnimation:
     UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

    [tv.tableView endUpdates];
    [tv.tableView reloadData];

    // back to first view ( UITableView view)
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And this is my first View : 
//dataObj is NSMutableArray , i create it to store contact data then i use it to display in UITableView

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.dataObj = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}
 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {

        return [self.dataObj count];

    }

    - (UITableViewCell* )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
        if(cell==nil){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
                }

        cell.textLabel.text = [self.dataObj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }

    //handle when click add button
    - (IBAction)addButton:(id)sender
    {
        //go to second view ( view to fill out form)
        ContactViewController *vc = [[ContactViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
```

UPDATE
//====================================

In My FirstView , i add 2 method. But it gets Exception ( or Error):

-[Contact row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c46610
2014-04-01 22:10:43.750 TelephoneDemo[463:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Contact row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c46610'

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
        self.dataObj = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addContact:) name:@"didAddContact" object:nil];
    }


- (void) addContact:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    Contact *c = (Contact *) notification.object;

    self.dataObj = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.dataObj addObject:c];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:self.dataObj withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

           [self.tableView endUpdates];
           [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: where is the IBOutlet property

Comment: @Spynet in other .h file

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you should have to read the Apple Documentation

Please study from here itself.

[UITableView Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are going wrong.

```
/*telephoneViewController is a class that store my TableView ( it is the first view)
    */
    TelephoneViewController *tv = [[TelephoneViewController alloc] init];
    tv.dataObj = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

You are not supposed to create a new instance of `TelephoneViewController`. Since it is different from the view controller where you are coming from. For simplicity i will explain you, Suppose you have two view controller VC `A` and VC`B`. Form VC `A` you are moving to VC `B` by pushing. Within `B` you are creating a new instance of VC `A`(called `A1`) and setting its array. and moving back to VC `A`. See here `A` and `A1` two different instance of the same class. So how VC `A` will get the data if you are setting it for VC `A1`. I hope you got it now. This is a common most of the beginners do.

So here the solution is you should follow the **delegate** pattern to pass the data between view controller.

Comment: thanks you for rep, it's exactle my problem.I think i must initialize it first ( alloc - init).  I must read carefully Delegate document .

Comment: You should not initialise it again. You should have the same instance of VC A in VC B. Anyway check how delegate works. You must know the concept. and let me know if you have any specific doubts

Answer (score 0):

Check Anil's answer for what's currently wrong with your code.

Here's how you can get things moving.

1. In your first ViewController's `init` or `viewDidLoad` method, use NSNotificationCenter to listen to a specific event, eg: `didAddNewContact`. The code would look something like:

   ```
   [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector:(addContact:) name:@"didAddNewContact" object:nil];
   ```
2. In the same ViewController's dealloc or similar method, you should also remove self from observing that notification.
3. In your second ViewController, when the user taps the save button, you simply do something like this instead of creating a new instance of the table:

   ```
   Contact *c = [[Contact alloc] init];
   c.name = self.nameText.text;
   c.company = self.comText.text;
   c.phoneNumber = self.phoneText.text;
   c.email = self.emailText.text;
   c.address = self.addressText.text;

   [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didAddNewContact" object:c];

   // back to first view ( UITableView view)
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   ```

   What happens here is that the notification center sends out a notification which our first view controller will catch.
4. Remember when we started listening for the notifications? We used the selector `addContact:`. Time to implement that.

   ```
   - (void)addContact:(NSNotification *)notification
   {
       // This is the same one the user created. Use this as required by the logic
       Contact *c = (Contact *)notification.object;

       // Now you can either reload the data by calling reloadData on the UITableView or use the insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation method. 

       //This assumes you have properly implemented the UITableView Datasource protocol methods in your view controller or elsewhere
       NSInteger section = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView]-1;

       NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] inSection:section];

       [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for rep. But should i connect it to what?? I run my App and receive a message : unrecognized selector

Comment: you get that error on which line?

Also, have you implemented addContact? That's the only unrecognized selector that could you get that I know of.

Comment: Yes i have implemented it. But i still receive message : Contact row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance, 

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Contact row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Can you please post the code where this error occurs? Doesn't seem related to the code I've posted. Do note: there is no `row` property on your `Contact` object.

Comment: i've updated my code ! i add 2 new method , i posted it, they're method which get error

Comment: You're passing an NSMutableArray composed of Contact Objects to the `tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths` call. You should be instead passing an array of NSIndexPaths to this method. I've updated my answer's addContact method to include this.

Comment: it doesnt work. I think NSMutableArray can contain object ( addObject) . So, i think my pro is connection to selector but i dont understand why it gets error

Comment: Both NSIndexPath and your custom Contact are objects (NSObject is their superclass). If you see your error, it happens because the tableView's datasource method tries to access the row property on your Contact object, and since no such property exists on your object, it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Using delegate you can get solution. Go through below code,

In second controller's .h file

```
@protocol PopOverViewControllerDelegate;

@interface PopOverViewController : UITableViewController
{
   //Declare your variable
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<PopOverViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol PopOverViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)PopOverViewController:(PopOverViewController *)viewController
             didChooseValue:(NSString *)value;

@end
```

In secondcontroller's .m file

```
id<PopOverViewControllerDelegate> strongDelegate = self.delegate;
[strongDelegate PopOverViewController:self didChooseValue:selection]; // selection means, your value to send back.
```

Declare popoverControllerDeleage in firstcontroller's .h file, then in firstcontroller's .m file

```
-(void)PopOverViewController:(PopOverViewController *)viewController didChooseValue:(NSString *)value
{
    NSLog("%@",value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks correct, just make sure that your tableview delegate methods are getting called after you reload data.

Comment: The OP's code is far from correct. Anil's answer gives a solid explanation on what's wrong.